# Threading issue when want to have a looping update to the UI from a background thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to update the UI in a loop in Android but I am getting an error that says that I am on the wrong thread.  I don't see why since I am using a handler.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
TextView textView;
protected Handler handler=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        textView.setText((String)msg.obj);  
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thread_sleep);
    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    init();
}

public void init()
{
    CounterThread counterThread=new CounterThread();
    counterThread.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_thread_sleep, menu);
    return true;
}

class CounterThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        int counter=0;

        handleString("in Thread handler");
        try{Thread.sleep(2000); }catch(Exception e){Log.d("Exception", e.toString());}

        while(counter<10)
        {
            counter++;
            String counterString=String.valueOf(counter);
            handleString(counterString);

            try{Thread.sleep(2000); }catch(Exception e){Log.d("Exception", e.toString());}
        }//while
    }//run 

    public void handleString(String string)
    {
        Message msg=handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj="counter"+" "+string;
        handler.handleMessage(msg);
    }

}//thread
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happens because you are not executing the code on the UI thread. So, you shoulde use the method runOnUiThread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

So, it's something like this:

```
protected Handler handler=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        final String msgString = (String)msg.obj;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            void run() {
                textView.setText(msgString);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: FYI, you've completely defeated the purpose of using the `Handler` by solving it in this fashion.  The point of `Handler` is for it to execute the code on the main thread for you, but you must first call it appropriately to pass the message along.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `Handler` incorrectly.  From your background thread, call `handler.sendMessage()` to post the message to the queue.  This will subsequently call the `handleMessage()` method on the `Handler` when it goes to process it.

As a side note, if you are only using the background thread to wait a certain amount of time before updating the UI again, you might look at using `sendMessageDelayed()` instead.  `Handler` is capable of doing it's own timing without you having to create a second `Thread`.